# Detecting balls on a pool table (stripes and solids)

Tags: java, opencv

I couldn't find any satisfying answer on that topic. I want to make a program that will get snapshots from camera above the pool table and detect balls. I am using OpenCV and Java. My algorithm now is basically:

blurring image -> converting RGB to HSV -> splitting into 3 planes -> using Canny() on H plane -> using HoughCircles() method to detect balls

This algorithm detects balls quite well, it has problem with two balls only (green and blue, because background of the table is green). But I want to go one step further and:

- Detect if the ball belongs to stripes or solids
- Set an ID of every ball, stripes would have for example 1-7 and solids 8-14, every ball would have unique ID that doesn't change during the game

Do you have any idea how to implement task #1? My idea is to use inRange() function, but then I'd have to prepare a mask for every ball that detects that one ball in specified range of colors, and do this detection for every ball, am I right? Thanks for sharing your opinions.

@Edit: Here I give you some samples of how my algorithm works. I changed some parameters because I wanted to detect everything, and now it works worse, but it still works with quite nice accuracy. I`ll give you three samples of original image from camera, image where I detect balls (undistorted, with some filters) and image with detected balls.

[image: Original image number 1]
[image: Canny image number 1]
[image: Image with detected balls number 1]

[image: Original image number 2]
[image: Canny image number 2]
[image: Image with detected balls number 2]

Comment: Try posting a sample image for users to test their hypothesis. Even green colored ball is not of same color as green table background.

Comment: I can see detecting solids but stripes would be difficult. I think your best bet would be to get another camera involved and start making comparisons and cross-checking.

Comment: Apologies for bringing an old post back. If you don't mind me asking two unrelated questions: 1) does applying Canny() on the H plane improve the performance of HoughCircles(), or are you employing Canny() for something else, and 2) how did you undistort the pool table?

Answer (score 3):

**Recommendation:**

If you can mask out the pixels corresponding to a ball, the following method should work to differentiate striped/solid balls based on their associated pixels:

1. **Desaturate** the ball pixels and **threshold** them at some brightness `p`.
2. **Count** the number of white pixels and total pixels within the ball area.
3. **Threshold on counts:** if the proportion of white pixels is greater than some threshold `q`, classify it as a striped ball. Otherwise, it's a solid ball.

(The idea being that the stripes are white, and always at least partially visible, so striped balls will have a higher proportion of white pixels).

---

**Sample Testing:**

Here's an example of this applied (by hand, with `p = 0.7`) to some of the balls in the *unrectified* image, with final % white pixels on the right.

It looks like a classification threshold of `q = 0.1` (minimum 10% white pixels to be a striped ball) will distinguish the two groups, although it would be ideal to tune the thresholds based on more data.

[image]

If you run into issues with shadowed balls using this method, you also can try rescaling each ball's brightnesses before thresholding (so that the brightnesses span the full range 0, 1), which should make the method less dependent on the absolute brightness.

Comment: I'll try this out next week and make some updates on the topic. If someone else has some ideas at setting the ball ID or sth then feel free to share.

Comment: For ball ID you can maybe get away with just finding the dominant hue of each ball's pixels (convert to HSV, take a saturation-weighted average of the hue values), then sorting balls by their hue values to get a canonical ordering (since regardless of the lighting, the relative hues should be in the same order). You would need special cases for the white/black balls, though. A more powerful option is to use histogram intersection (https://mpatacchiola.github.io/blog/2016/11/12/the-simplest-classifier-histogram-intersection.html), or just compute histogram feature vectors and train an SVM.

Comment: Can you tell me Ollin, what did you mean by saying "threshhold at some brightness"? Is this brightness a third parameter in java threshhold method implementation? And how did you count pixels on a circle? I tried to use meanStdDev method but it requires Rectangles so it isn't too accurate.

Comment: Oh! I mean using `threshold` (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#threshold-org.opencv.core.Mat-org.opencv.core.Mat-double-double-int-) with `p` as the threshold. I think you can count white/black pixels by using a histogram (http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/04-opencv-basics.html) with the mask argument set to be the pixels of the circle, then using the top bin as the number of white pixels and the bottom bin as the number of black pixels.

Comment: One more question, can you tell me exact parameters that u used in your example? Because when I do threshhold then yellow and orange solid balls are mostly white, I guess my parameters aren't right.

Comment: Okay now I detect every ball on the L layer of HLS image because it is most accurate. There is a problem with yellow solid ball (too many white pixels), striped yellow ball (small amount of white pixels!!!!) and purple striped ball (small amount of white pixels)

Comment: The image I posted used Lightness (same as your comment). For the yellow/purple balls, you can try rescaling/normalizing the brightnesses before thresholding, or (equivalently, I think?) making the threshold adaptive (i.e. `threshold = k + (1-k) * (average lightness of ball)` for some `k` in [0,1]). In the worst case, you can do dominant hue computations _first_ and make a lookup table that maps hue ranges -> thresholds (so, higher threshold for yellow, low threshold for purple).

Comment: Okay in my case the most accurate was to take G and B layer from RGB image, equalize hist on it, then make a function that takes average white pixel percentage from those 2 layers and that's it. I also made a statement that if white pixel percentage increases more than 3 times then the function takes lower value (that was the case with yellow and blue ball). I have last question, because detecting white ball is okay (in most cases it has the biggest amount of white pixels :p), but I have a problem with differentiating black ball from brown (very similar amount of white pixels). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused–it sounds like you're trying to use the number of white pixels to differentiate colors? Number of white pixels should work for striped vs. solid, but for distinguishing colors you would want to use a hue-based method as I mentioned in my first comment. In any case, you can hopefully differentiate the black ball and brown ball by their average saturation or average value (or some combination of both), since the brown ball will be lighter and more saturated.

Comment: I mean I wanted to use the number of white pixels just to differentiate white and black ball. I thought that white ball will have most white pixels, and black ball least. No more questions then, I'll handle it with the method u mentioned. Thank you for help, cheers!

Comment: @OllinBoerBohan What do you mean by "desaturating the ball pixels"? Do you mean converting the pixels to grayscale (in the second and fourth column of the provided picture)?

Comment: Yes, 2nd and 5th columns (where saturation level has been set to 0, giving a grayscale image)